# Just following the FastAuth SDK documentation won't do the job

Tags: nearprotocol

I've been practicing with the NEAR Fast Auth SDK documentation and encountered a problem while setting up the frontend on GCP.

An error occurred, and I've uploaded a video to https://youtu.be/yyP9sJ1k91E detailing my process. Could you please review it and help me identify where I might have gone wrong?